# how to name two columns dependind on another column value for a table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to name two columns for a table in SQL server.

table1:

```
id  type   value
1   th   81648   
1   nh   9794
2   nh   7689
2   th   9895
```

I need to get a table:

```
id value_th  value_nh  // the column names depend on type
1  81648     9794
2  9895      7689
```

How to design the SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `pivot`.  I prefer conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when type = 'nh' then value end) as value_nh,
       max(case when type = 'th' then value end) as value_th
from table t
group by t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a simple join with nested selects:

```
select t1.id,t1.value_nh ,t2.value_th  from 
(select id, value as value_nh where type='nh') t1
join (select id, value as value_th where type='th') t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```